# How come pandas pd.SparseDataFrame never completes for large data sets?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have the following python3 code that doesn't seem to complete.  Is there an estimate for how long this takes?  I would like to be able to use sparsedataframes because a large number of the elements are 0 value.

```
>>> s_matrix
<12000x61190 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>' with 1577553 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> sdf = pd.SparseDataFrame(s_matrix)
```

This has been running for hours and still hasn't completed.  Similarly, I was able to load the 1.3GB data set into a dataframe, but the sdf = df.to_sparse() never completed and I ended up aborting the run.

Any help for speeding up the conversion to SparseDataFrame would be appreciated.

Comment: SparseDataFrame constructor is ridiculously slow when number of columns is large....